# Babysitting dragons

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Connect each baby dragon with its parent to solve each mini-puzzle.  The connections can not intersect and must cover the whole board.

[image]

The answer is [image]:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On the face of it, this seems too easy... I presume I'm missing something, but I'll spring the trap for everyone!

> [image: babysitting dragons]

I suppose the next stage is to use the answer key:

> The lines of the answer key (when superimposed) seem to spell TIAMAT
>  [image: superimposed message]
>  Ha! I decided to google tiamat on the off-chance that it really was a word and what do you know! "A Tiamat is a supremely strong and powerful 5-headed draconic goddess in the Dungeons & Dragons role-playing game. [Tiamat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiamat)

Very cool puzzle! Thanks

Comment: I think it's ok to write an easy puzzle once in a while which holds most of its value in its aesthetics :-)

Comment: I completely agree. It's probably harder to make a puzzle like this than to solve it which I also appreciate!